# How to config Facebook/Meta pixel to Next Js project

Tags: facebook, next.js, facebook-pixel

I need to integrate Facebook pixel to a Next Js project. My project loads the script on the head from a SEO component. If I add the pixel in the _app component, this load on the body instead the head

I was trying with Vercel example in its repo, but it not working.

This is my code in _app

```js
         <Script
            id="fb-pixel"
            strategy="afterInteractive"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
               __html: `
            !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
            {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
            if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
            n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
            t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
            'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
            fbq('init', ID FACEBOOK);
          `,
            }}
         />
```